# How to stop SPSS from altering cell decimal values at import from .csv

Tags: spss

I'm importing roughly 50.000 cases/rows into SPSS via .csv file.

The data in question consists of a total of 17 variables some of which contain numbers. 
They're basically Decimals but they get changed by SPSS when I import them.

The problem is I can't set a particular variable to have 3 Decimals because the actual value can sometimes be 2, which is important to keep as is and at other times it is actually 3. Hence, if I set the whole variable to 3 Decimals the values containing only 2 Decimals get added a 0 at the end, which screws everything up for me.

Snippet from actual data:

[image]

I need 1.667 to stay as-is. Then I need 1.50 to stay as-is. Then 1.40, 1.364 and so on for everything.

What happens when I import it is 1.50 becomes 1.500  1.40 becomes 1.400 and so on and so forth..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original data is `1.25` them the actual data stored is 1.25, which is equal to 1.250, and to 1.250000 for that matter. So this shouldn't screw up any calculations you are making - just the display.

You are forced to decide whether to rounded to two decimal points (`1.25') or three ('1.250'). If indeed this is what's bothering you - To the best of my knowledge there is no way (unlike Excel) to have a different number of decimals for different parts of one column, nor is there a way to remove trailing zeros.

This being said here is a weird workaround: changing the number format to 'restricted numeric' should, in theory, make your data unacceptable (as numbers in this format aren't supposed to have fractions), but will show the data without trailing zeros (well, in version 23 on my machine it does at least).

you can change the format through syntax like this:

```
formats var1 to var7 (n8).
```

Comment: It makes a bit more sense now. Thanks for explaining and for the suggestion!